# how to add views in viewflipper to the left side in android

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am trying to have a viewflipper which adds imageviews to the left.currently when I addviews to the viewflipper using

viewFlipper.addview (image);

The images are added to the viewflipper on the right side.

child 0->child 1-> child 2-> child 3-> etc

I want to have childviews added to the viewflipper from right to left.

<- child 3 <-child 2 <- child 1 <-child 0

Is there a property which I am missing ? or should it be done explicitly ?

Comment: Did you tried `viewFlipper.addview (image, 0);`?

Comment: use #addView(View child, int index) to add views to a particular index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

or

```
addView(View child, int index)
```

add the view at index 0 to get your desired effect

Answer (score 0):

Add the views to your ViewFlipper object in the order like

```
child 3 at index 0
child 2 at index 1
child 1 at index 2
child 0 at index 3
```

Which results to display child3 as first element and child 0 as last element.